# Removing from array when not in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a function that calls GPS coordinates from an PHP file trough AJAX to display them on a map and this all works fine.

The function checks if the marker that its getting is already on the map and if it is it updates it location, if it isn't on the map it adds it too the map.

What i need now and can't seem to get working is that i need to delete previous used markers that arent updated any longer.

Here is my code:

```
setInterval(
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: 'markers.php',
                success: function(data){
                    var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
                    for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++) {
                        newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(json_obj[i].lat, json_obj[i].lng);
                        if (markersArray[json_obj[i].name] && markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setPosition){
                            markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setPosition(newcoordinate);
                            if(json_obj[i].type == 'onderweg') {
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setIcon(onderweg);
                                var label = markersArray[json_obj[i].name].getLabel();
                                label.color="black";
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setLabel(label);
                            }
                            if(json_obj[i].type == 'leeg') {
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setIcon(leeg);
                                var label = markersArray[json_obj[i].name].getLabel();
                                label.color="black";
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setLabel(label);
                            }
                            if(json_obj[i].type == 'bezet') {
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setIcon(bezet);
                                var label = markersArray[json_obj[i].name].getLabel();
                                label.color="white";
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setLabel(label);
                            }
                            if(json_obj[i].type == 'afwachten') {
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setIcon(afwachten);
                                var label = markersArray[json_obj[i].name].getLabel();
                                label.color="black";
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setLabel(label);
                            }
                            if(json_obj[i].type == 'pauze') {
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setIcon(pauze);
                                var label = markersArray[json_obj[i].name].getLabel();
                                label.color="black";
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setLabel(label);
                            }
                            if(json_obj[i].type == 'geendienst') {
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setIcon(geendienst);
                                var label = markersArray[json_obj[i].name].getLabel();
                                label.color="black";
                                markersArray[json_obj[i].name].setLabel(label);
                            }
                        } else {
                            addMarker(json_obj[i].lat, json_obj[i].lng, json_obj[i].name, json_obj[i].afkorting, json_obj[i].type);
                        }

                    }
                },
                dataType: "json"//set to JSON    
            })    
        }
    ,3000);
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction to fix this?

Json data:

```
[{"id":"1505108","0":"1505108","name":"Benny","1":"Benny","afkorting":"Be","2":"Be","address":"","3":"","speed":"0","4":"0","lat":"53.198181","5":"53.198181","lng":"6.563437","6":"6.563437","type":"onderweg","7":"onderweg","ts":"2017-04-17 18:26:34","8":"2017-04-17 18:26:34","ritid":"483648","9":"483648","bedrijf":"1","10":"1","ipadres":"188.207.111.80","11":"188.207.111.80","versie":"10","12":"10","inactief":"0","13":"0","beta":"0","14":"0","onzichtbaar":"0","15":"0"},{"id":"1505110","0":"1505110","name":"Rene","1":"Rene","afkorting":"Re","2":"Re","address":"","3":"","speed":"0","4":"0","lat":"53.182274","5":"53.182274","lng":"6.577085","6":"6.577085","type":"leeg","7":"leeg","ts":"2017-04-17 18:26:37","8":"2017-04-17 18:26:37","ritid":"0","9":"0","bedrijf":"1","10":"1","ipadres":"188.207.126.119","11":"188.207.126.119","versie":"10","12":"10","inactief":"0","13":"0","beta":"0","14":"0","onzichtbaar":"0","15":"0"},{"id":"1505112","0":"1505112","name":"Peter","1":"Peter","afkorting":"Pr","2":"Pr","address":"","3":"","speed":"0","4":"0","lat":"53.196129","5":"53.196129","lng":"6.581492","6":"6.581492","type":"bezet","7":"bezet","ts":"2017-04-17 18:26:39","8":"2017-04-17 18:26:39","ritid":"483650","9":"483650","bedrijf":"1","10":"1","ipadres":"92.69.203.230","11":"92.69.203.230","versie":"10","12":"10","inactief":"0","13":"0","beta":"0","14":"0","onzichtbaar":"0","15":"0"},{"id":"1505113","0":"1505113","name":"Ivar","1":"Ivar","afkorting":"Iv","2":"Iv","address":"","3":"","speed":"0","4":"0","lat":"53.360897","5":"53.360897","lng":"6.414318","6":"6.414318","type":"onderweg","7":"onderweg","ts":"2017-04-17 18:26:39","8":"2017-04-17 18:26:39","ritid":"483649","9":"483649","bedrijf":"1","10":"1","ipadres":"188.207.122.118","11":"188.207.122.118","versie":"10","12":"10","inactief":"0","13":"0","beta":"0","14":"0","onzichtbaar":"0","15":"0"},{"id":"1505114","0":"1505114","name":"Niels","1":"Niels","afkorting":"Ni","2":"Ni","address":"","3":"","speed":"0","4":"0","lat":"53.205700","5":"53.205700","lng":"6.586080","6":"6.586080","type":"bezet","7":"bezet","ts":"2017-04-17 18:26:40","8":"2017-04-17 18:26:40","ritid":"483633","9":"483633","bedrijf":"1","10":"1","ipadres":"92.69.223.185","11":"92.69.223.185","versie":"9","12":"9","inactief":"0","13":"0","beta":"0","14":"0","onzichtbaar":"0","15":"0"},{"id":"1505109","0":"1505109","name":"John","1":"John","afkorting":"Jo","2":"Jo","address":"","3":"","speed":"0","4":"0","lat":"53.200897","5":"53.200897","lng":"6.596990","6":"6.596990","type":"leeg","7":"leeg","ts":"2017-04-17 18:26:36","8":"2017-04-17 18:26:36","ritid":"0","9":"0","bedrijf":"1","10":"1","ipadres":"92.69.230.150","11":"92.69.230.150","versie":"10","12":"10","inactief":"0","13":"0","beta":"0","14":"0","onzichtbaar":"0","15":"0"}]
```

Array echo:

```
[_.Ne, _.Ne, _.Ne, _.Ne, _.Ne, _.Ne, Benny: _.Ne, Rene: _.Ne, Peter: _.Ne, Ivar: _.Ne, Niels: _.Ne…]
```

This is what i get.. but every object has its own values and the script does work..

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just replace the entire marker array with what was returned. There would be no updating or deleting.

Comment: what does your array originally look like ? maybe `if(in_array) { /* array_push / set new value */ }` could do it ?

Comment: @RusselMadere I did that before but then all the markers are going to flicker on every update and thats kind of annoying.

Comment: @OldPadawan in_array just checks if it's in the array, i still won't know wich one's need to be deleted...

Comment: @HarmJanvanKammen : can you please show the original array, and the expected output for the final array ?

Comment: @OldPadawan Wich one? The one i get from json or the one i store? And could you point me to how to do it? Never dit it before.

Comment: @HarmJanvanKammen : both please. In order to show you a possible correct way out, I need to see what you're using :) please update the question with these

Comment: @OldPadawan I updated it but it may be bringing up more questions

Comment: @HarmJanvanKammen, I'll need to think on this to prevent there from being undefined elements in your array. If each element in the array had a unique identifier, you could use that to identify the elements to remove and then use the pop() method on the array to remove the marker. It'll take some doing to prevent the map from flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get a chance to fully test this, but you can try this. I will say that it isn't very efficient. You loop through two arrays, but at least the loops are not nested.

First change your success handler slightly (Empty lines added for highlighting).

```
            success: function(data){

                var idArray = [];

                var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
                for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.length; i++) {

                    idArray.push(json_obj[i].id);

                    newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(json_obj[i].lat, json_obj[i].lng);
                    ...
```

Then loop through the array of markers (referred to here as array, use your array name) in reverse and splice the markers array that do not exist in the new idArray.

```
for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (idArray.indexOf(array[i].id) < 0) array.splice(i, -1);
}
```

By working in reverse, you won't mess up the indexing of the earlier array members.

I have an array of points in a mapping application that I have to add and remove points on the fly. There we replace the array and then re-render the map.

More info on splice - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice